# Abaqus/Python fixed seeding constraints

Tags: python, mesh, abaqus

I am working with Abaqus/Python for a finite element analysis. I've got the following problem: I have a 3D domain which consists of a 2D domain containing edges as well as circle segments and which is extuded in the third dimension. Now I want to mesh that domain with the constraint that only one element along the thickness direction has to be used. Following minimal example of an extruded quarter circle in Python code:

```
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
import __main__

# Sketch quarter circle
s = mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', 
    sheetSize=50.0)
g, v, d, c = s.geometry, s.vertices, s.dimensions, s.constraints
s.setPrimaryObject(option=STANDALONE)

s.ArcByCenterEnds(center=(0.0, 0.0), point1=(0.0, 5.0), point2=(5.0, 0.0),
    direction=CLOCKWISE)
s.Line(point1=(0.0, 5.0), point2=(0.0, 0.0))
s.Line(point1=(0.0, 0.0), point2=(5.0, 0.0))


# Create part from sketch and extrusion in the depth
p = mdb.models['Model-1'].Part(name='Part-1', dimensionality=THREE_D,
    type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)
p.BaseSolidExtrude(sketch=s, depth=0.1)
s.unsetPrimaryObject()
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=p)
del mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__']

# Mesh
# Global seeds
p.seedPart(size=0.35, deviationFactor=0.1, minSizeFactor=0.1)
# 'fixed' seeding constraint: only one element in thickness direction
e = p.edges
pickedEdges = e.findAt(((5.0, 0.0, 0.025), ), ((0.0, 5.0, 0.025), ), 
    ((0.0, 0.0, 0.025), ))
p.seedEdgeByNumber(edges=pickedEdges, number=1, constraint=FIXED)

# Generate mesh
p.generateMesh()
```

In the last line, when I want to generate the mesh, the domain cannot be meshed because the 'fixed' seeding constraints cannot be honored. If I use

```
p.generateMesh(seedConstraintOverride=ON)
```

to generate the mesh, the domain can be meshed, but only with two elements in the thickness direction. Is there a way to mesh the domain with only one element in thickness direction? If not, why?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this. One option is to simply change the mesh technique to **sweep**. For example, assuming your part consists of a single geometric cell (like in your example code), you can use the following:

```
part_cells = p.cells()
p.setMeshControls(regions=(part_cells[0],), technique=SWEEP)
p.generateMesh()
```

You must give the `region` keyword argument as a sequence of Region or Set objects. Notice that if the length of the sweep direction is smaller than the global seed size, then you don't need to specify any edge seed constraints and only one element will be generated.

Comment: I want to take up the question again. You said, that there are a couple ways to do this. Which other ways are there instead of using the mesh technique sweep?

Comment: Did the original answer work for you? Depending on your model and needs, you can also try: (1) bottom-up meshing, or (2) create a 2D mesh part, and extrude it. Similar concepts, different tools to accomplish the goal.